# python regular expression to match js or php url

Tags: python, regex

I tried to match js and php url with python re
but expression below doesn't work, anyone can help me?

```
import re, urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.cnn.com')
s = response.read()
p = re.compile(r'^(http|https|//).+?\.(js|php)$')
m = p.findall(s)

for i in m:
    print i
```

Also, some Web pages use `//`, not `http` or `https`. Is there any way to match those, too?

Comment: If you are actually parsing URLs, you might look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html. If you're practicing regexes ... forge ahead.

Comment: Try `re.compile(r'\b(https?)://(.+?)\.(js|php)\b')`

Comment: hi ,thank you for your answer! some webpage use '//' ,not http or https ,is there any way to match it.

Comment: Try `re.compile(r'\b(https?|//).+?\.(js|php)\b')`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to match URLs that end with file extensions `js` and `php`, that may start with `http`, `https` or `//`.

Use

```
import re
s = "https://www.cnn.com/1.js!! http://www.cnn.com/2.php; //some.site.com/3.js,"
res = re.findall(r'(?:\bhttps?:)?//\S*\.(?:js|php)\b', s)
print(res)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/b4CEXk)

**Details**:

- `(?:\bhttps?:)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\b` - a leading word boundary
  - `https?:` - `http`, 1 or 0 (=optional) `s`, and a `:`
- `//` - a literal char sequence `//`
- `\S*` -  zero or more non-whitespace symbols
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:js|php)` - `js` or `php` literal char sequences
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary